# Timeout issue in CURL command in shell script

Tags: curl

I am having a curl command as follows

```
curl --max-time 900 --location --request GET "https://XXXXXX/YYYYY?taskName=AssertTag_Task&projectName=POC" --header "Content-Type: application/json" --header "Authorization: Basic a2FydGhpa2E3ODk6MmQ0dWI0OTNGM0VTM3BtdXpxUl123456FOd3ph"
```

The above API takes around 5minutes to return the response.
After around 4minutes the following error gets thrown by the curl command

500 - The request timed out.

### 500 - The request timed out.

The web server failed to respond within the specified time.

The API it is trying to hit is hosted in apache tomcat.
Any idea where we have to reset the timeout period.

Comment: You're receiving an error *from the server*. Nothing you do on the curl command line will effect the timeout.

Comment: Any idea where in server we have to modify the timeout

Comment: We got the issue finally. The webserver is in azure app service. Azure app service returns 500 timeout error if any request is idle for more than 230seconds.